# Is there a way to loop through text box values in C++?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, c++-cli, clr

I have 50 text boxes that I want to get text from. I want to loop through these texts instead of getting each text individually.

**What i currently have**

getting values:

```
array <System::String ^, 49> s;
s[0]=this->TextBox0->Text;
s[1]=this->TextBox1->Text;
...
s[49]=this->TextBox49->Text;
//do stuff with s
```

**What Im looking for**

```
array <System::String ^, 49> s;
for (int i = 0; i <= 49; i++)
{
    s[i]=this->TextBox[i]->Text;
}
// do stuff with s
```

Im not sure how to iterate through the textboxes.

Comment: Judging by the code you show, that's not possible. You also have an off-by-one error: your array has no element with index 49.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox?view=netframework-4.7.2); It is reasonable to assume that 'textbox1' and so forth, reference some large number of identically typed objects within the user-defined subclass of "form." A better solution would involve the following:

```
private std::array<TextBox> TextBoxes(49);
```

Otherwise, if the objects can be simply be a regular distance apart in memory, the following work-around could also function.

**The following code SHOULD NOT be used in a professional code-base**

In addition to issue of relying upon a consistent arrangement of the boxes in memory, this solution also risks writing and reading from invalid memory locations, as there are no guaranteed boundaries, as is the case with a standard array.

```
size_t stepSize = static_cast<char*>(&(this->TextBox1)) - static_cast<char*>(&(this->TextBox0));

s[i] = (static_cast<TextBox*>(static_cast<char*>(&(this->TextBox0) + stepSize * i)))->Text;
```

This simply takes the distance between the first two textboxes in the form's memory (in bytes, to avoid alignment issues), and uses that distance to extrapolate the address of the other textboxes.